# How to show column field values in different textboxes

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table **UserProfile** which have fields-

**UserId,
 FirstName,
 LastName,
 Password, 
 EmailId,
 MobileNumber.**

Now I want that when I execute **select query** where userId is **A1001** in sql server.

It bring values of all the fields in textboxes. Like-

```
TextBox1.text = FirstName.value,

TextBox2.text = LastName.value
```

and so on.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can use datatable.

Comment: How to use it. I am not able to do using datatable. Please explain.

Comment: Pleas check this [link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/261046/how-to-retrieve-data-and-display-in-textbox-in-c) and do the changes in your code accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this...

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        txtFirstName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtLastName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
        txtEmailId.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EmailId"].ToString();
        txtMobileNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MobileNumber"].ToString();
```